# I have VBA code for creating new folder its working whoever slight problem with link which is concatenated

Tags: excel, vba

I have query regarding creation of folder based on selection. VBA code seems to be working whoever i want to make more effortless. Here are some issues

1. Reference Number in Column D is actually a hyper link, which has been given a friendly or should i say face name in order to keep sheet clean for its users. VBA codes seems to be not working because i have friendly or face name for the link.
2. in order to run code successfully On other hand what i did i create duplicate of column D but without giving any face name to links. this allowed to run vba code successfully. however problem with this is when select cell with link i need to press create folder button to create folder each time. what i want is instead of click create button it should create folder if a cell with link is selected.

it would be great if someone could provide a fix for issue No. 1, where folder should be created, on selection of cell from column D containing link but as well as face name.

For ease of understanding, see below table to understand the structure of my sheet:

```
A:1 Contains Default Starting Name P195-HCT
B:1 Contains Default path (\Desktop\HCT)

A:5 to A:100 contains Revision No.
B:5 to B:100 contains Serial number for Folder
C:5 to C:100 contains formula which is (=HYPERLINK($B$1&B5&" "&"R"&A5,$A$1&B5&" "&"R"&A5)
```

Code:

```
Sub MakeSekectionDir()

For Each x In Selection
    If x = "" Then

    ElseIf Len(Dir(x, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir x

    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

What I want is this:

A folder should be created, on selection of cell from column D containing link but as well as face name.

The VBA code should be able to create a folder if any cell from C:5 to C:100 is selected.

Comment: First of all please use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of every module and then `Dim` every variable, i. e. `Dim x As Range`. Then you can use `For Each x In Selection.Cells` and `x.Value` to identify individual cells and their value.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `DIR` use `FSO` (FileSystemObject). DIR is an old dog and should be shot. FSO has many more uses and you can use FSO within an FSO loop...